# Android : How to disable Keyboard or making enable only the numeric in EditText onClick

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'am having EditText in my application which is to display DatePicker. I'am seeing the keyboard when i click the EditText and if i again click the EditText strongly then my DatePicker is coming. I don't want to show the keyboard to the user. How can i achieve this scenario?

This is my code.

```
dataandtime = new EditText(getActivity());
     dataandtime.setLayoutParams(params1);
     dataandtime.setWidth(1000);
     dataandtime.setTextAppearance(context, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
     dataandtime.setHint("Set Date and Time");
     dataandtime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(context, mTimeSetListener, mhour, mminute, false);
            tpd.show();
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                    mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
            dpd.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your EditText only numeric use this in your Java:

```
   dataandtime.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

or this in your XML:

```
   android:inputType="number"
```

To disable the keyboard, try this in your activity's declaration in ManifestFile:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
   </activity>
```

Comment: I have one more doubt. If i click the EditText it calls the DatePicker and again if i click outside of the Dialog then also it calls the TimePicker. I want to call the TimePicker only if i set the DatePicker value is done.

Comment: Call the TimePicker in the DatePicker's listener, here, this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677761/datepickerdialog-ok-button-not-getting-the-selected-date

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TextView with a proper background